# Visual Studio compatibility with Win CE 5/6/7 Platform

Tags: visual-studio, windows-ce

I am developing a scanner program to be compatible with WinCE 5/6/7 platform. 
Since VS 2008 is out of MS support, I am looking for a later version of VS to develop the program. However after trying out different third party tools (like toradex etc.) not able to get any conclusion. For VS 2015 there is .Net compact framework 3.9 which supports only WinCE 8 platform not the prior versions.

Request for your advice to proceed further. In case I need to post under a different category, please suggest.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read **[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** to let us help you better 

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately VS2008 is the latest dev tool supporting those OS releases. You should be able to get together with platform builder from a windows embedded distributor or as part of an msdn subscription where you should be able to download previous releases. I say "should" because Ms license terms and distribution policies may have changed since the last time I checked this.